# HTML background image on full screen: I try to put a picture as background but it cuts the picture for me I want it to stay full size

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

The image works for me and is displayed on the screen, but when I make it the background, it cuts off part of it, which lowers the quality of the image and looks bad. I would appreciate your help, thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style> 
html { 
  background: url("{% static 'images/second.JPG' %}") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't have all your image as full screen if its aspect ratio differs from the viewport's aspect ratio - using cover as you have done the system has to either cut the top/bottom or the sides to make it fit. If you want the see the whole image everytime you can use contain instead of cover, but then  you will get margins at either the sides or top/bottom.